# modRewrite to translate path into complex filename

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can I make modrewrite translate an url to a php filename?

```
mysite.com/part1       (or mysite.com/part1/)       --> part1.php
mysite.com/part1/part2 (or mysite.com/part1/part2/  --> part1_part2.php
```

Comment: Should this work for any number of directories of is it only one or two levels?

Answer (score 1):

```
# turn on rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On

# remove trailing slash
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [L]

# translate slash to underscore
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ $1_$2 [L]

# if there is no .php extension, add it
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

You can consider some more conditions like to not manipulate existing files/directories and append query string (`QSA` argument to rewrite rules)